# How to make Jquery changes on element with attribute runat="server"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have two html tables (`table1` and `table2`).
table1 added the `runat="server"` attr because on `page_load` I am adding its rows.
The goal I am trying to achieve is that when pressing on a row from `table1`, that row will move to `table2` and also the opposite way around.
I am doing this using Jquery on the webform.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $('.excluded').click(function () {
           var tr = $(this).clone();
           tr.removeClass("excluded");
           tr.addClass("included");
           $(this).remove();
           $('#table1').append(tr);
       });

       $('.included').click(function () {
           var tr = $(this).clone();
           tr.removeClass("included");
           tr.addClass("excluded");
           $(this).remove();
           $('#table2').append(tr);
       });
   });
```

The "included" and "excluded" are id's on the rows.
I was able to move row from `table1` to `table2`, but i cant move row from `table2` to `table1` because of the `runat="server"` attr on `table1`.

Is there any workaround? (another solution to my problem would also be great)

Comment: `runat="server"` has nothing to do with jQuery, JavaScript code runs entirely on the client.  If you want to use JavaScript to modify your HTML in the browser, look at the HTML and see what it actually looks like.

Comment: Silly me... you are correct, after some more debug I see that my problem is related to something else. I will post a new Q regarding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

include ClientIDMode="static" in your markup of that element..

That will prevent asp.net from changing the ID of the element.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it did not solved my problem but i sure learned something new! it turns out that David was correct and the problem is not related to the runat attr